# How to read the crash log of the IOS appstore?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am publish the APP to the AppStore but it tells me the APP crashed while open it.

but no matter I open it on my mobile or the simulator it runs well I can not find why it crashed.

here is the crash log:

```
We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Version:             1.2 (1.2)
AppStoreTools:       11E146

Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2020-04-13 17:18:24.5761 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-04-13 17:18:24.1051 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_507  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b05d4df0 0x1b05ae000 + 159216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04f4930 0x1b04f2000 + 10544
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b0482934 0x1b040c000 + 485684
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b04828c0 0x1b040c000 + 485568
4   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001041856d8 0x102e88000 + 19912408
5   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x000000010417d564 0x102e88000 + 19879268
6   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104092ee8 0x102e88000 + 18919144
7   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104034084 0x102e88000 + 18530436
8   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104034874 0x102e88000 + 18532468
9   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104029a00 0x102e88000 + 18487808
10  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000102f98e88 0x102e88000 + 1117832
11  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001032915ec 0x102e88000 + 4232684
12  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x000000010404460c 0x102e88000 + 18597388
13  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001040df328 0x102e88000 + 19231528
14  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001040e4564 0x102e88000 + 19252580
15  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001040293e0 0x102e88000 + 18486240
16  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104183bc8 0x102e88000 + 19905480
17  涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000102eb37a4 0x102e88000 + 178084
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b05df1ec 0x1b05de000 + 4588

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9c0 0x1b04f2000 + 39360

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9c0 0x1b04f2000 + 39360

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9c0 0x1b04f2000 + 39360

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9c0 0x1b04f2000 + 39360

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9c0 0x1b04f2000 + 39360

Thread 6 name:  SGen worker
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b05d4bc0 0x1b05ae000 + 158656
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04f71e4 0x1b04f2000 + 20964
2   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x000000010415b2e4 0x102e88000 + 19739364
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04f38fc 0x1b04f2000 + 6396
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9d4 0x1b04f2000 + 39380

Thread 7 name:  Finalizer
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b05b27c0 0x1b05ae000 + 18368
1   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104095198 0x102e88000 + 18928024
2   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x0000000104111874 0x102e88000 + 19437684
3   涓尰鍏哥睄.iOS                          0x00000001041116ec 0x102e88000 + 19437292
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04f38fc 0x1b04f2000 + 6396
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9d4 0x1b04f2000 + 39380

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b05b2784 0x1b05ae000 + 18308
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b05b1ba8 0x1b05ae000 + 15272
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0769080 0x1b06bc000 + 708736
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0763e0c 0x1b06bc000 + 687628
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0763660 0x1b06bc000 + 685664
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b0aad6a8 0x1b0aa5000 + 34472
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b0aad580 0x1b0aa5000 + 34176
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b49dd420 0x1b3ecb000 + 11609120
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b0be77a0 0x1b0aa5000 + 1320864
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04f38fc 0x1b04f2000 + 6396
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b04fb9d4 0x1b04f2000 + 39380

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000034   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x0e25c6c1570e32cc  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000bf3d01
   x12: 0x00000001522a4000  x13: 0x0000000000004009  x14: 0x00000001522a4000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001f0f2a808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000507  x21: 0x00000001048ce120  x22: 0x0000000000000003  x23: 0x0000000152027400
   x24: 0x000000015228a760  x25: 0x00000001045c41a8  x26: 0x000000016cf76550  x27: 0x0000000104358868
   x28: 0x0000000152027268   fp: 0x000000016cf75760   lr: 0x00000001b04f4930
    sp: 0x000000016cf75740   pc: 0x00000001b05d4df0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

At last there is a Adderss size fault.I do not know why?

and I can not find the reason.

please help me thankyou.

Comment: This crash log does not make much sense. Have you tried running your app in the iphone/ipad with iOS system 13.4.1 to check if there is any crash?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have tried running my app in the iPhone in both release and debug mode .it do not crashed. and the IOS system is 13.4.1

Comment: No idea what happened during the review. You can try to submit again and ask for more information.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT thankyou . I will try on the appcenter which tell me do not use personal data on device. Can I upload the certificate of IOS? does my code safe?

Comment: I think your code is safe in appcenter. Just don't share any private, sensitive personal data there.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  I tried and failed Is is because the chinese project name?

Comment: I don't know. Did you get any error message?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I get the message which says: File not found in the Assets.xcassets? but I have set the AppIcon.

Comment: You upload it to appCenter? I think this is another question and you can open a new thread with information there.